# Modify Object literal data and wrap it in the array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object literal or like a json file which has data in it, what I want is to wrap the SMBPremium and MAX data inside an array so that I can target by accessing its index. How Can I modify my object literal to an array so that I can target SMBPremium and MAX. Kinda like this.

```
productMap['TEC0'][1].productName;
```

This is my json

```
var productMap = {
    "TEC0": { 
      "SMBPremium"  : {
                "productName": "Wilson",
                "panelClass": "WilsonClass",
                "fullinfoClass": "Wilsonfull",
                "productPageLink": "",
                "panelPageLinkGA": "",
                "fullPageLinkGA": "",
                "notifLinkDanger" : {
                    "linkPrimary" : "",
                    "linkSecondary" : ""
                    },
                "notifLinkRed" : {
                    "linkPrimary" : "",
                    "linkSecondary" : ""
                    },
                "notifLinkInfo" : "",
                "notifLinkWarning" : "",
                "notifLinkSuccess" : ""
        },

        "MAX": {
                "productName": "Spalding",
                "panelClass": "spalding",
                "fullinfoClass": "spalding",
                "productPageLink": "",
                "panelPageLinkGA": "",
                "fullPageLinkGA": "",
                "notifLinkDanger" : {
                    "linkPrimary" : "",
                    "linkSecondary" : ""
                },
                "notifLinkRed" : {
                    "linkPrimary" : "",
                    "linkSecondary" : ""
                },
                "notifLinkInfo" : "",
                "notifLinkWarning" : "",
                "notifLinkSuccess" : ""
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried 
`Object.values(productMap["TEC0"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate the object productMap formatted like you wish:

```
// Every object is a map:
var tec0 = productMap['TEC0'];
var keys = Object.keys(tec0);
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    var value = tec0[key];
    array.push(value);
}

var newProductMap = {'TEC0': array};

alert(newProductMap['TEC0'][1].productName);
```

**NOTE**: Faly's answer is far more elegant. Just be carefull at browser compatibility with arrow functions (IE does not support  for example).

Idem for Ammar's answer, not supported by IE.

Comment: I give this as the best answer, but I gave thanks to all of the people who answers, yes Faly's answer is more elegant. however your code is more simple to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Tranform with *array.map*:

```
productMap2 = {};
productMap2.TEC0 = Object.keys(productMap['TEC0']).map(key => productMap['TEC0'][key]);
```

Then you can access *productName* property for each element:

```
productMap2.TEC0[1].productName
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

***try this***

```
index = 1
productMap['TEC0'][Object.keys(productMap['TEC0'])[index]].productName;
```

***Explanation***

- productMap['TEC0'] is an json object
- Object.keys(productMap['TEC0']) - will return json object keys as array.
  in this example like this  ["SMBPremium", "MAX"]
- Object.keys(productMap['TEC0'])[index] - will return key name based
  on index passed.
- productMap['TEC0'][key_name]    - will fetch json object based
  key_name got from previous state.

Comment: This might answer the question. Would you mind extending it, for fellow programmers, to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method:

```
productMap["TEC0"] = Object.values(productMap["TEC0"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the items to an index of the wanted keys array.

```js
var productMap = { TEC0: { SMBPremium: { productName: "Wilson", panelClass: "WilsonClass", fullinfoClass: "Wilsonfull", productPageLink: "", panelPageLinkGA: "", fullPageLinkGA: "", notifLinkDanger: { linkPrimary: "", linkSecondary: "" }, notifLinkRed: { linkPrimary: "", linkSecondary: "" }, notifLinkInfo: "", notifLinkWarning: "", notifLinkSuccess: "" }, MAX: { productName: "Spalding", panelClass: "spalding", fullinfoClass: "spalding", productPageLink: "", panelPageLinkGA: "", fullPageLinkGA: "", notifLinkDanger: { linkPrimary: "", linkSecondary: "" }, notifLinkRed: { linkPrimary: "", linkSecondary: "" }, notifLinkInfo: "", notifLinkWarning: "", notifLinkSuccess: "" } } },
    keys = ['SMBPremium', 'MAX'];
    
keys.forEach((k, i) => productMap.TEC0[i] = productMap.TEC0[k]);

console.log(productMap['TEC0'][0].productName);
```